# locustio installed falid error: legacy-install-failure error: subprocess-exited-with-error

Tags: python-3.x, macos, pip, package, locust

how to install locustio

```
study_locust /usr/local/bin/python3.8 -m pip install  locustio              
Looking in indexes: http://pypi.byted.org/simple/pypi/+simple
Collecting locustio
  Downloading http://pypi.byted.org/packages/pypi/locustio/locustio-0.999.tar.gz (267 kB)
     ━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━ 267.6/267.6 kB 741.2 kB/s eta 0:00:00
  Preparing metadata (setup.py) ... done
Installing collected packages: locustio
  DEPRECATION: locustio is being installed using the legacy 'setup.py install' method, because it does not have a 'pyproject.toml' and the 'wheel' package is not installed. pip 23.1 will enforce this behaviour change. A possible replacement is to enable the '--use-pep517' option. Discussion can be found at https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/8559
  Running setup.py install for locustio ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error
  
  × Running setup.py install for locustio did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─\> \[4 lines of output\]
      running install
      
      \*\*\*\* Locust package has moved from 'locustio' to 'locust'. Please update your reference (or pin your version to 0.14.6 if you dont want to update to 1.0) \*\*\*\*
      
      \[end of output\]
  
  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
error: legacy-install-failure

× Encountered error while trying to install package.
╰─\> locustio

note: This is an issue with the package mentioned above, not pip.
hint: See above for output from the failure.
➜  study_locust
```

Comment: Have you read the error message?

Answer (score 1):

> × Running setup.py install for locustio did not run successfully.
> │ exit code: 1
> ╰─> [4 lines of output]
> running install
>
> ```
>  \*\*\*\* Locust package has moved from 'locustio' to 'locust'. Please update your reference (or pin your version to 0.14.6 if you dont want to update to 1.0) \*\*\*\*
>  
>  \[end of output\]
> ```

https://docs.locust.io/en/stable/installation.html

`locustio` is no longer the name of the package. As the error message and docs say, you need to install `locust`.

`pip3 install locust`